# How to find the port after typing netstat -b for class

Tags: netstat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X17v.png)"4. At the prompt, type netstat -b and then press the Enter key on your keyboard.  a. Select two active connections. Name the active applications (*.exe), the port(s) that are in  use, and the destination IP addresses."

I honestly don't know where to locate the port. Attached is a screen shot.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

- Explorer.EXE - active app
- port 49728
- destination IP address and port 52.226.139.121:https

---

```
[Explorer.EXE]

TCP 192.168.1.100:49728    52.226.139.121:htpps    ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: 52.226.139.121:https is an IP address and port, not just the destination IP.

Comment: @user16632363 Thx for clarifying  I made change.